# How many elements of order 3 can a group of order 36 have?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

If $G$ is an abelian group of order $36=2^2\cdot3^2$, elements of order 3 must live in subgroups of order 3 or 9. Now, by Sylow, there could be either 1 or 4 3-Sylow-subgroups (of order 9).

If $n_3=1$ then the subgroup of order 9 is either $\mathbb{Z}_9$ or $\mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3$ (must be abelian, and those are all abelian of order 9), and here we can explicitly count number of elements of order 3.

If $n_3$ = 4, then, since $G$ is abelian, every one of the 3-Sylow-subgroups are conjugate to each other, but they are also normal, thus they coincide with each conjugates; this is, it cannot be $n_3=4$.

Ok, I believe this solves the abelian case, even though I have a question: could you solve this (in the abelian case) without showing / counting explicitly the number of elements in the 3-Sylow-subgroup?

I am stuck in the non abelian case though. The beginning should be the same: there are either $n_3=1$ or $n_3=4$ 3-Sylow-subgroups. If there is only one, count as before (as $3^2=9$ groups of order 9 are all abelian). But if there are $n_3=4$ subgroups of order 9, how would you count the number of elements of order 3?

Thank you all in advance,

Regards

Comment: For abelian groups, the Sylow theorems are both overkill and not really informative. Finite abelian groups (indeed, finitely _generated_ abelian groups) are very well understood, and there are, up to isomorphism, $4$ abelian groups of order $36$ (in my book, this result came a few chapters _before_ the Sylow theorems). It's easier to check them one by one than trying to divine information from the cryptic Sylow.

Comment: If $n_3=4$ then since $9$ does not divide $4!=24$, there must be an element of order $3$ in the kernel $K$ of the conjugation action of $G$ in its Sylow $3$-subgroups, and since $G/K$ also has $n_3=4$, we must have $|K|=3$. So the $4$ Sylow $3$-subgroups intersect pairwise in $K$. The cyclic case is easy - the only elements of order $3$ lie in $K$. The $C_3 \times C_3$ case needs more careful couniing.